# Flyway 4.0 commandline creates empty metadata table

Tags: mysql, percona, flyway

I'm admittedly a newbie to Flyway, but I don't think I'm missing anything obvious.  I've tried a number of very basic executions, and cannot get flyway to populate it's "metadata" table.  I'm connecting to a remote Percona MySQL database:

```
Server version: 5.6.29-76.2-log Percona Server (GPL), Release 76.2, Revision ddf26fe
```

The simplest example I can come up with to demonstrate this is executing the following:

```
flyway -password='db_pass' -url='jdbc:mysql://XX.XX.XX.XX:3306/db_schema' -user='db_owner' -locations='filesystem:/home/adam/flyway' migrate
```

With a sql script at `/home/adam/flyway/V1.1__Cars.sql`:

```
CREATE TABLE `cars` (
  `id` bigINT(20) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  `license_plate` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  `color` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL
);
```

It's also important to note that the script itself IS executed when `flyway migrate` is called.  The default metadata table of `schema_versions` is created as well.  It also is created during baseline operations.

I've tried out every configuration option that would seem to make sense and it has no impact with regards to populating the metadata table (schemas, user, locations, baselineOnMigrate, table, baselineVersion and others).

Oh, and I also tried briefly the mariadb driver.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not an issue with flyway 3.2.1

Thanks

Comment: Thank you, Saima.  This does work, and is helpful, at least as a short-term solution.

Answer (score 0):

By default the Flyway Command-line distribution comes with the MariaDB driver, which is used for MySQL and Percona (`jdbc:mysql:...` urls) and MariaDB connections (`jdbc:mariadb:...` urls).

The newer version of this driver seems to have an incompatibility with Percona though. You can resolve this by downloading the official MySQL Connector/J JDBC driver and simply dropping the jar file in the `/drivers` directory of your Flyway installation.

Everything should then work as expected.